# Proof of order trichotomy for integers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers. I have to proof that exacly one of the statements $a >b$, $a<b$ or $a=b$ is true.

So, I have to proof two things:

1) We can't have more than one statement true.

2) At least one of the statements is true.

The first part I did but the problem is in the second part of the proof.

Considering the  order trichomotomy for natural numbers, one can prove the second part by induction, but how can I use induction for integers? That's my question.

So, how can I prove the second part? I think that with a hint I can do it. (be aware of circularities though)

Comment: This is an axiom that can not be proved

Comment: are you sure? there's an exercise from Terence Tao's analysis I book for which the solution requires this proof

Comment: By induction I can prove this for positive integers, but for the negative ones I think that I can estabilish a correspondence between the negative ones and their negations  (hence positive, so the trichotomy is already proved). And since there's an equivalence between the negative integers and their negations, so the trichotomy order its proved for all integers. But I am not sure of this.

Comment: That depends on which system you use. It looks like using Peano system to define integers

Comment: How are $\mathbb{Z}$ and the order $<$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ defined?

Comment: the integers are defined as a subtraction of naturals. The order.. hmm it's just like if  $a \geq b $ then a=b+c and c is a positive number (not incluiding zero)

Comment: Hmm, "as a subtraction of naturals" isn't very specific. Is it as equivalence classes of ordered pairs of naturals under the equivalence relation $(a,b) \sim (c,d) \iff a+d = c+b$, so that $(a,b)$ (or more precisely the equivalence class $[(a,b)]$ of the pair) corresponds to $a-b$?

Comment: you wrote the definition of equality for integers.. If an integer x=a-b and y=c-d are equal iff a+d=c+b.. And a, b, c and d are all naturals, hence an integer x is defined as a subtraction of naturals.

Answer (score 0):

We will use the Trichotomy of Integers. Define $x:=a-b$. We know that $x$ itself is a integer and hence only one of these hold, $x=0$ or $x>0$ or $x<0$. Each corresponds to one of the cases that we want to show.